# Why does python ignore my other lines of code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
mark = raw_input

if mark < 50:
    print "your mark is unsatisfactory!"

else:
    print "your mark is satisfactory!"
```

I want to create something that gives an answer depending on what number the user inputs. However, when I run the code it only shows "your mark is satisfactory!" and I can't seem to figure out why it's not letting me input a number.

Comment: You need to actually call `raw_input`, like `raw_input()`. At the moment you are just creating a reference to the function.

Comment: Short answer is that `raw_input()` (notice the parentheses!) returns a *string* not an integer.  This is a duplicate, although I can't find the dupe target off-hand

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `raw_input`.  Right now you're just taking the value of the function, which is always True (because for Python, functions are truthy). Add some parentheses to make it `raw_input()` to actually call the function.  Also you'll want to call `int(raw_input())` to get an integer from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Call `raw_input`, like

```
mark = int(raw_input("enter something"))

if mark < 50:
    print "your mark is unsatisfactory!"
else:
    print "your mark is satisfactory!"
```

Note the conversion to int, since `raw_input` returns a string.

At the moment all you are doing is creating another variable that refers to the function `raw_input` and comparing it against 50.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you don't call the function.

You have to do:

```
answer = raw_input('your question')
```

Also, the type of the `answer` is `str`. Because it looks like you want to compare it with number, you have to transform into a number:

```
answer = int(answer) # if you want an int
answer = float(answer) # if you want a float
```

Note:

by doing

```
mark = raw_input
```

`mark` is now equal to the function, witch means that if you do `mark('...')`, it would do the same thing than `raw_input('...')`